# QnA Markdown formatting gets lost on using Transalation API

Tags: azure-qna-maker, microsoft-translator

I have been using Microsoft Translator API v3.0 which does not seem to work in my case.

[image]

The Translation actually appends spaces and the markdown gets scrambled. How to fix this?

Thanks,
deeepss

Answer (score 1):

The ! indicates a sentence end, which is not what you want in this case.
You can escape the exclamation point to a tag like <exclamation>. Then it will be handled as a word in the context of the sentence.
[image: Postman example of request and response]